# Lucee Throwing error on OpenOffice and JODConveter

Tags: java, coldfusion, lucee, jodconverter

I had the following Lucee + JODConveter ehich i am trying now,

I am constantly getting an error

```
Lucee 5.3.4.80 Error (com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException)
Message     conversion failed: could not save output document; OOo errorCode: 2074
```

I installed Latest OpenOffice 4 version and even lucee on my local but i am still wondering what is going on it, does it have any permissions issue, any config changes i need to do, any clue?

Comment: What version of JODConverter are you using?  There seems to be several repositories out in the wild that are no longer maintained.  Here's one that's still actively updated. https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter

Comment: i had these files for jod converter, bunch of jar files with dependencies, http://prntscr.com/rnx4ld   , if there are any new files, how can i get those all jar file. i do not know how to compile the files into the jars like this one

Comment: also, it uses the docx, instead of doc

Comment: before i was using this with old version `<cfobject type="java" class="com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter" name="jodDocumentConverter">
  <cfobject type="java" class="com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.SocketOpenOfficeConnection" name="jodOpenOfficeConnection">` , now with new version, the path and classes are not there

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough to help you with your Lucee script. But here are the libraries you need to use jodonverter-4.3.0

- [org.jodconverter:jodconverter-local:4.3.0](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jodconverter/jodconverter-local/4.3.0/jodconverter-local-4.3.0.jar)
- [org.jodconverter:jodconverter-core:4.3.0](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jodconverter/jodconverter-core/4.3.0/jodconverter-core-4.3.0.jar)
- [org.openoffice:juh:4.1.2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openoffice/juh/4.1.2/juh-4.1.2.jar)
- [org.openoffice:jurt:4.1.2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openoffice/jurt/4.1.2/jurt-4.1.2.jar)
- [org.openoffice:juh:4.1.2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openoffice/juh/4.1.2/juh-4.1.2.jar)
- [org.openoffice:unoil:4.1.2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openoffice/unoil/4.1.2/unoil-4.1.2.jar)
- [com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar)
- [commons-io:commons-io:2.6](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar)
- [org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar)
- [org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar)

Now, you may want to read the [wiki pages](https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter/wiki) of the [jodconverter](https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter) project to help you translate your script using the new jodconverter version.

There are 2 ways to use the jodconverter library with a local OpenOffice (or LibreOffice) installation, depending on if you are managing the office instances yourself, or if you let jodconverter manage them.

If you use jodconverter on the server side of an application, the best approach is to let jodconverter manage the office process, that would be started on application start, and closed on application shutdown.

You may take a look at [this webapp sample](https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter/tree/master/jodconverter-samples/jodconverter-sample-webapp) that does just what I explained.

Good luck!

Note that OpenOffice is known to have some difficulties working with docx file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45072953/4336562). Maybe you could just try with LibreOffice ??